# Environment issue in moving from protobuf version 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I have generated the protobuf code using the compiler 2.4. And I have created my application jar. This works fine and I can successfully run my spark job. 
The jars in classpath of spark relevant to protobuf are

```
 mesos-0.18.1-shaded-protobuf.jar,
 protobuf-java-2.5.0-spark.jar
```

But when I use the same generated code in my sbt unit testing it is failing with

```
  [info]   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage        
  failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
  Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost):     
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.                                                         
  [info]  at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getUnknownFields(GeneratedMessage.java:180)
```

From google search I found that I need to change the protoc compiler to version 2.5 and Now My unit testing works fine .
But my application is not able to run in spark . The exception I get is

```
  java.lang.VerifyError: class xxx.xxx.xx.. 
  overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

The machine where my application runs and my sbt test runs are different

Class path in sbt contains

```
  protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
  protobuf-java-2.5.0-spark.jar
```

I had a look in pom file mesos-0.18.1-shaded-protobuf.jar it shows it contains google-protobuf version 2.5 .

The questions are 
what is the problem in the environment that is causing this issue ?

Comment: I found out the problem was due to hive-exec.jar which was in the classpath of spark job.

Comment: The problem was one of the dependent jar in my sbt is evicting the protobuf jar version to higher one . This caused my sbt test to fail. Now I have forced the jar version dependency using the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065982/how-to-override-the-dependency-of-an-sbt-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Basically with protocol buffers 2.5, several methods went from being defined as final in the *protocol buffers library code* to being in the generated code. This means that code generated with **protoc 2.4** can not be used with *protocol buffers 2.5 libraries* and **vice versa**

---

As you correctly identified

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by classes.                                                         
    [info]  at   com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getUnknownFields(GeneratedMessage.java:180)
```

is the message you get when you run code generated by **protoc 2.4** with the libraries for **protocol buffers 2.5**

---

The message

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class xxx.xxx.xx.. 
overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

is the message you get when you run code generated by **protoc 2.5** with the libraries for **protocol buffers 2.4**.

see: [error with serialization with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908268/error-with-serialization-with-protobuf/15913425#15913425)